# Send Email with Confidential Mode On in Google Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

Do we have any option to send email with Gmail Confidential Mode on with Google Apps script? I checked in the [Gmail API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/insert) but couldn't find anything.

Comment: New feature. Probably hasn't made into the api yet.

Comment: As @TheMaster said, the feature is new, so it still hasn't made it to the API, there is an [open Issue Tracker issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/140572178) regarding this, consider clicking "+1" in it to increase its priority.